# Data not displaying through ViewModel

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I am newbie to android development and not able to understand why the data is being not displayed. initially the lists are empty so it should show empty text view but it is not showing that also.

Here's the code
**Viewmodel factory**

```
public class ViewModelFactoryListItFragment implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    String category;
    Application application;

    public ViewModelFactoryListItFragment(Application application,String category ) {
        this.category = category;
        this.application = application;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> aClass) {
        if (aClass.isAssignableFrom(ViewModelListItFragment.class)) {
            return (T) new ViewModelListItFragment(application, category);
        } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Viewmodel not found");
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModelListItFragment extends ViewModel {

    private AppDatabase mDb;
    private LiveData<List<ListItEntry>> myEntries;
    private Application mApplication;
    private String mCategory;

    public ViewModelListItFragment(@NonNull Application application, String category) {

        this.mCategory = category;
        this.mApplication = application;
        mDb = AppDatabase.getInstance(mApplication);
        myEntries = mDb.listItDao().getListItsByCategory(mCategory);


    }

    public LiveData<List<ListItEntry>> getMyEntries() {
        return myEntries;
    }


}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class ListItFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentListItBinding mBinding;
    private ViewModelListItFragment mViewModel;
    private String mCategory;

    public ListItFragment(String category) {
        super();
        this.mCategory = category;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Timber.i("List it fragment created");
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_list_it, container, false);

        ViewModelFactoryListItFragment factoryListItFragment = new ViewModelFactoryListItFragment(this.getActivity().getApplication(), mCategory);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, factoryListItFragment).get(ViewModelListItFragment.class);
        LiveData<List<ListItEntry>> entries = mViewModel.getMyEntries();
        entries.observe(this.getViewLifecycleOwner(), listItEntries -> {
            if(listItEntries == null || listItEntries.size() == 0){
                mBinding.textEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mBinding.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            mBinding.textEmpty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mBinding.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        });
        return mBinding.getRoot();

    }
```

I have not yet implemented recylerview adapter so it will not show existing data but when the entries are not there then also it is not showing empty textView.

Comment: set visibility to GONE instead of INVISIBLE and check. Also if you can post layout code that will be helpful.

Comment: Try your `mBinding.textEmpty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` and `mBinding.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in else part. since its outside `if` your textView is invisible again.

Comment: @ShahnawazAnsari the lines ```            mBinding.textEmpty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);            mBinding.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);``` outside if block so it was not working. it works now.. Thanks.. but now how do I close this question. should I answer it myself or delete it?

Comment: @Dashesh in layout it was already set to GONE. the problem was with if block only thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    entries.observe(this.getViewLifecycleOwner(), listItEntries -> {
            if(listItEntries == null || listItEntries.size() == 0){
                mBinding.textEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mBinding.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                mBinding.textEmpty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mBinding.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Your code is outside if part thus even though your condition is met the part outside your if is being executed. Add an else part to make sure that it doesn't get executed as shown above